# Get video play of youtube player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, youtube

I'm creating this webpage on wordpress which have videos from youtube in some of it's posts, for tagging purposes I need to capture everytime a person clicks play on each of the videos. I've looked through the web, but all I could find is that, since this videos are on iframes from outside the main domain, it's impossible to catch something from the inside of it, like clicks.

Is there any way that I can catch this clicks on the play button without changing anything on the site? Just from JS.

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture some *events* within the `iframe` using youtube's [js API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

This is what you have to do:

1). Load the [Player API](http://www.youtube.com/player_api) in your page

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

2). Enable `jsapi` in your `iframe` as a trailing parameter (`enablejsapi`) like

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/opj24KnzrWo?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0" width="420" height="280" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

... also **notice** we added an *ID* to the `iframe`.

3). Create 3 functions :

a). `onPlayerReady` :

Here is where you can detect when the video has loaded and is ready to play. Here you can actually start the video, etc.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    // video is ready, do something
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

b). `onPlayerStateChange` :

Here is where you can detect what *events* are triggered:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log(event.data); // event triggered
    // e.g. end of video
    if (event.data === 0) {
        // end of video: do something here
    }
}
```

When you `click` *play* or *pause*, an *event* is triggered. Then you can decide what action you want do, including pushing a tracking *event*, etc.

This is a list of the returned values of each *event* :

```
-1 – unstarted
 0 – ended
 1 – playing
 2 – paused
 3 – buffering
 5 – video cued
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) to learn more about those *events*

c). `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` :

This is where you actually initialize the API and bind the *events* to the other functions :

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var id = document.getElementById("myIframe").getAttribute("id");
    var player = new YT.Player(id, {
        events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
} // youtube API ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/93urwzgd/)**